# Is there Entity Framework support for saving to multiple databases on the same SQL Server in single transaction?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two databases on the same SQL Server instance. I would like to write a record to each database in a single transaction.

In Linq-to-SQL, I would connect to either database with one context and use *three part naming* to identify the tables.

Is there a similar capability in Entity Framework?

I'm trying to avoid DTC, it has been forbidden - so the usual `TransactionScope` approach is not available to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way I know of... you could potentially use the *UnitOfWork* pattern

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581487/Unit-of-Work-Design-Pattern

That might allow you to at least go back to the other `Db` and un-commit?

Personally I think your going to struggle.